# Overloading insertion operator in Boost.Log (Boost 1.60.0)

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I am trying to overload `operator<<` so that I can log `vector<T>`s in Boost.Log. I tried overloading the `formatting_ostream`:

```
template <typename T>
inline boost::log::formatting_ostream & 
operator<< (boost::log::formatting_ostream & o, const std::vector<T> & v) {
    return o;
}
```

This does not compile with Boost 1.60.0

I am using the following logger:

```
typedef boost::log::sources::severity_logger<
    boost::log::trivial::severity_level
> my_logger_t;
```

The errors that I see are:

> .../boost_1_60_0/build/include/boost/log/utility/formatting_ostream.hpp:799:19:
>
> error: no match for `operator<<` (operand types are
>   `boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::basic_formatting_ostream<char>::ostream_type
>   {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}` and `const std::vector<int>`)
>
> strm.stream() << value

As I understand, the overloading doesn't work!!
Because the compiler is still calling the pre-defined `operator<<` which makes the `strm.stream() << value` call.

Am I doing something wrong?
What's the best way to go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like an ADL problem: operator<< is in neither boost::log nor the std namespaces, so it doesn't get picked up during name lookup.

Comment: Daamn! Indeed! Just wrapping the overload within `namespace boost { namespace log { ... } }` resolved it.

Thanks a lot @KazDragon :)

Comment: Answerified my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an ADL problem: since operator<< is in neither boost::log nor the std namespaces, it doesn't get picked up during name lookup.